# nodejs - TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string, Buffer - when using callback response with http.request

Tags: node.js, http, callback

- TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or Array-like Object. Received type number
  at Function.from (buffer.js:305:9)

Answer (score 0):

In quite a number of times : getting an [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE] error implies that a certain argument or parameter is needed for the node app or which ever app you are attempting to run, to run properly.

#### SCENARIO #1 : .env   [[image: (related) 1]]

A few checks to look out for example; in the case of parameters being defined into .env file for the (node) application to function :

1. Check if the .env file has been properly defined or created for the app
2. Are the needed parameters for the node app to work all well defined in your ".env" file ?
3. If the parameters are not there define them, example :

   PORT=3000

   PATH=/home/data/images/

   HOST=http://localhost

   DB_NAME=test_db

And to access them :

```
process.env.PORT
process.env.PATH
process.env.HOST
process.env.DB_NAME
```

With the above done, any errors in relation to [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE] should clear when now you issue your command in the terminal to run the node application.

#### SCENARIO #2 : http.request  (related)

Please I definitely encourage you to check your code again, there might be some parameter or argument you are required to have defined or should have set in place before the node app can run properly.

You may refer to SCENARIO #1 to make sure all or any parameter or argument is properly defined and try running the app again.

I would love to know if the suggested answer above was helpful or if you did something else to fix it, do share. Thanks and best wishes.